# Adding subviews to UIView subclass for use with Core Graphics

Tags: ios, uiview

I have a subclass of `UIView` to use Core Graphics.

I have the `UIViewController` for that view as well.

I want to add regular non-Core Graphics `UIView`s to that view subclass.

Do I add the `UIView`s as a subviews to `self.view` (`[self.view addSubview:view]`) in the view controller or do I add them as subviews in the `UIView` subclass file (`[self addSubview:view]`)?

Using Objective-C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both options are possible - you have to decide what makes the most sense.

If you intend to reuse the UIView subclass in another view controller, and it doesn't need the Core Graphics subviews, you should put this logic in the view controller. Otherwise, I'd put it inside the UIView subclass, as the amount of code in the UIViewController tends to get rather large very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Does not matter, in that the outcome will be the same. It just depends on your coding style / application architecture, i.e. where do you want to setup the views that you add as subviews.